# Angular 9 - How to call RestAPI without refresh the page?

Tags: angular, observable

I am developing a SPA application, using Angular CLI 9.0.7, that has a user registry. The user, after being registered, can change his profile picture at any time. For this I created a service that shows a modal window where the user selects his image, and the service returns the image in an object.

This image is then sent to be persisted in the backend, but when the call is made to API Rest, the page is reloaded.

This is my HTML file:

```html
<img 
    src="{{ imgProfile }}" 
    class="img-fluid img-thumbnail mx-auto" 
    (click)="onClickSelectNewImage()" 
/>
```

This is my method to show modal service:

```js
onClickSelectNewImage(): void {
    let currentImg: string = this.imgProfile;

    this.modalService.showModalInputImage('Profile', currentImg, this._id).subscribe(
        (img: IImagemBase64) => {
            this.onUpdateImage(img);
        },
        (error: any) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

This is returned by modal service:

```js
export interface IImagemBase64 {
    id: string;
    fileName: string;
    imageBase64: string;
}
```

This is the API call:

```js
private onUpdateImage(img: IImagemBase64) {
  if (img && img.fileName) {
    this._userService.updateUserImage(img).subscribe(  // when this line is executed the page is reloaded - :/
      (success: ICommandResponse) => {
        const user: IUser = <IUser>success.data;
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This is the backend service call:

```js
public updateUserImage(request: IImagemBase64): Observable<ICommandResponse> {
  let url: string = `${this._url}/${request.id}/imagem`;

  return this._http.put<ICommandResponse>(url, request).pipe(take(1));
}
```

> How can I submit a request without reloading the page?

Comment: what are you doing exactly in that `updateUserImage` method? this is not like normal behavior

Comment: I´m sending the image to backend. Like this.

  public updateUserImage(request: IImagemBase64): Observable<ICommandResponse> {
    let url: string = `${this._url}/${request.id}/imagem`;

    return this._http.put<ICommandResponse>(url, request).pipe(take(1));
  }

Comment: put it in the question

Comment: What are you calling "page reload"? Your app is swiped out and a new instance is got from the server again? Or do you just mean that your dialog is closed? Angular `HttpClient` wouldn't reload your app alone. There must be something else (maybe an interceptor or something like that which is doing something like `window.location.href = ...`).

Comment: When I call the API the page flashes, recharging all the content. The strange thing is that the other CRUD methods are called the same and do not have this effect. But I will check if I have something like what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is the following: The backend is receiving a base64 string, transforming and persisting the image in the assets\images folder. It turns out that the images in the assets folder are static, optimized by the bundle. When an image is placed there, and as I am in a dev environment, the angular identifies a change, compiles, autalizes and reloads the application to reflect his changes.

To solve the problem the images must be **saved in another location**, a folder on the server or a CDN, for example.